# Capture button click in WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, webview, microsoft-metro

I'm currently making a Windows 8 app which contains a WebView. I'd like to know if there's any way to capture certain buttons/links inside the WebView with C#?
Example:

*Button ID "btnDoSomething"* is clicked inside the WebView -> C# captures the click, and starts a timer or redirects to another page, or similar action.

Is it possible? If it's a vague question, I'll try to explain in any way I can as it's quite a hurry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx) and [ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify), and in particular look at Scenario 4 of the [XAML Web View Control example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7) on the [Dev Center](http://dev.windows.com).

Comment: It seems like this requires me to have actual access to the files, and use a certain set of codes, right? Is there any way of doing this without having access to modify the files (as in, I'm not the owner of the website, so I can't add additional JS code to the website).

Comment: I have not tried, but if you look at Scenario 5 of that sample, it shows how you can inject script via eval.  You might be able to inject script to add a listener to the button or other DOM element that then calls window.external.notify.